# AzureML: ResolvePackageNotFound azureml-dataprep

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I've got a basic ScriptStep in my AML Pipeline and it's just trying to read an attached dataset. When i execute this simple example, the pipeline fails with the following in the driver log:

> ImportError: azureml-dataprep is not installed. Dataset cannot be used
>   without azureml-dataprep. Please make sure
>   azureml-dataprep[fuse,pandas] is installed by specifying it in the
>   conda dependencies. pandas is optional and should be only installed if
>   you intend to create a pandas DataFrame from the dataset.

I then modified my step to include the conda package but then the driver fails with "ResolvePackageNotFound: azureml-dataprep". The entire log file can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/372ht6jkvzu9loo/conda.err.txt?dl=0).

```
# create a new runconfig object
run_config = RunConfiguration()
run_config.environment.docker.enabled = True
run_config.environment.docker.base_image = DEFAULT_CPU_IMAGE
run_config.environment.python.user_managed_dependencies = False
run_config.environment.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=['azureml-dataprep[pandas,fuse]'])

source_directory = './read-step'
print('Source directory for the step is {}.'.format(os.path.realpath(source_directory)))
step2 = PythonScriptStep(name="read_step",
                         script_name="Read.py", 
                         arguments=["--dataFilePath", dataset.as_named_input('local_ds').as_mount() ],
                         compute_target=aml_compute, 
                         source_directory=source_directory,
                         runconfig=run_config,
                         allow_reuse=False)
```

I'm out of ideas, would deeply appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `azureml-sdk` isn't available on conda, you need to install it with `pip`.

```
myenv = Environment(name="myenv")
conda_dep = CondaDependencies().add_pip_package("azureml-dataprep[pandas,fuse]")
myenv.python.conda_dependencies=conda_dep
run_config.environment = myenv
```

For more information, about this error, the logs tab has a log named `20_image_build_log.txt` which Docker build logs. It contains the error where `conda` failed to failed to find `azureml-dataprep`

EDIT:

Soon, you won't have to specify this dependency anymore. the Azure Data4ML team says `azureml-dataprep[pandas,fuse]` is getting added as a dependency for `azureml-defaults` which is automatically installed on all images.

Comment: thanks, that worked!!! Out of curiosity, is there a list of supported pip & coda packages ?

Comment: @webber for pip you can search [http://pypi.org/](http://pypi.org/). for conda, i believe [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/) are the lists

Comment: don't mean to be a pain, but I've got a followup question. In our code, isnt "azureml-dataprep" a pip package too? If so, whats the reason we have a square braces with additional packages?

Comment: no worries -- it's confusing. the square brackets after `azureml-dataprep` indicate optional extra dependencies to install alongside `azureml-dataprep`. similar to the [`azureml-sdk` where you can optionally install other dependencies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/install?view=azure-ml-py#advanced-install-extras). `azureml-dataprep`'s options are strange because the options are literally their own packages. so you could also pass `pandas` and `fuse` own their own, using the options guarantees that `dataprep` has the versions of each package that it needs.